# What does `(.N)` do in this extended glob?

Tags: zsh, glob, prezto

The [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) documentation has the following example script for setting up symlinks:

```
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
for rcfile in "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.zprezto/runcoms/^README.md(.N); do
  ln -s "$rcfile" "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.${rcfile:t}"
done
```

I understand everything in `"${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.zprezto/runcoms/^README.md(.N)` up until `(.N)`. What does `(.N)` mean here?

Bonus question, what is `${rcfile:t}`? I understand that it resolves to the name of the `rcfile` but I don't know what the `:t` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The bellow piece denies or negates `(.N)` all content wich starts `'^'` with README.md `^README.md(.N)`*

The `^` symbol is a regular expression the means the beginning of something.

The `${rcfile:t}` part allows only the name stripping the dir name of string.
Therefore the loop will create a needed symlink for each configuration file of your *zpresto* dir.

Answer (score 2):

The glob (**extended** glob, actually) `^README.md(.N)` expands to all **files** **except README.md**, or returns **null** (an empty string).

**extended:** Set by the `setopt` line. Needed for the `^` (see below).

**files:** The *dot* in `(.N)` stands for files (not directories nor links).

**except README.md:** The `^`. Think of `^` inside brackets in a regex. That does **not** mean files beginning with README.md.

**null:** The *N* in `(.N)`. It says the globbing to return a null string if the expansion fails. Otherwise that line would return an error if `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.zprezto/runcoms/"` had only the `README.md` file or no files at all.